# Invalid property 'isDifferentLanguage' of bean class

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I´m new to the Spring MVC Framework and I´m having a problem. When trying to bind the Information of a form to my controller the following error occurs:

"Invalid property 'isDifferentLanguage' of bean class [de.pwc.form.FPagesCheckForm]: Bean property 'isDifferentLanguage' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?"

My aim is to prove if some checkboxes are checked. Strangely enough this code works for the second and third checkbox of my .jsp file. But for the first checkbox "Different language in the documents?" it is not working despite I have implemented getter and setter of the property.

This is a part of my .jsp File:

```
    Different language in the documents? <form:checkbox path="isDifferentLanguage"/><br/>
    Only compareNumbers <form:checkbox path="onlyCompareNumbers"/><br/>
    Markup <form:checkbox path="markup"/><br/>
```

This is my form:

```
private int startPageOld;
private int endPageOld;
private int startPageNew;
private int endPageNew;

private boolean isDifferentLanguage;
private boolean onlyCompareNumbers;
private boolean markup;

// Files
private CommonsMultipartFile[] fileDatas;

public CommonsMultipartFile[] getFileDatas() {
    return fileDatas;
}

public void setFileDatas(CommonsMultipartFile[] fileDatas) {
    this.fileDatas = fileDatas;
}

public int getStartPageOld() {
    return startPageOld;
}

public void setStartPageOld(int startPageOld) {
    this.startPageOld = startPageOld;
}

public int getStartPageNew() {
    return startPageNew;
}

public void setStartPageNew(int startPageNew) {
    this.startPageNew = startPageNew;
}

public int getEndPageOld() {
    return endPageOld;
}

public void setEndPageOld(int endPageOld) {
    this.endPageOld = endPageOld;
}

public int getEndPageNew() {
    return endPageNew;
}

public void setEndPageNew(int endPageNew) {
    this.endPageNew = endPageNew;
}

public boolean isOnlyCompareNumbers() {
    return onlyCompareNumbers;
}

public void setOnlyCompareNumbers(boolean onlyCompareNumbers) {
    this.onlyCompareNumbers = onlyCompareNumbers;
}

public boolean isMarkup() {
    return markup;
}

public void setMarkup(boolean markup) {
    this.markup = markup;
}

public boolean isDifferentLanguage() {
    return isDifferentLanguage;
}

public void setDifferentLanguage(boolean isDifferentLanguage) {
    this.isDifferentLanguage = isDifferentLanguage;
}
```

If you need more information just tell me ! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `<form:checkbox path="differentLanguage"/>` instead of `<form:checkbox path="isDifferentLanguage"/>`

Comment: Thanks! :) But why does that work?

Comment: Look at your other properties. `onlyCompareNumbers` -> `isOnlyCompareNumbers()`, `markup` -> `isMarkup()`. Only for `differentLanguage` you did it differently for some reason. But this has to do with a common JavaBeans convention, where the Java class has `get...()` or `is...()` methods for properties.